# In Angular jS trying to create two dropdown

Tags: angularjs, dropdown

I am trying to create two dropdown in Angular JS
First dropdown will have values:
"A","B","C"
When i select A it should show A1,A2,A3,A4 in second dropdown.Similarly for B  it should show B1,B2,B3,B4  and C it should show C1,C2,C3,C4

.Below are my two JSON

```
$scope.column = [{
        colid: 1,
        name:"A"
        }, {
        colid: 2,
        name: "B"
       }, {
        colid: 3,
        name: "C"
       }];

$scope.Value=[{"A":"A1","B":"B1","C":"C1"},
{"A":"A2","B":"B2","C":"C2"},
{"A":"A3","B":"B1","C":"C3"},
{"A":"A1","B":"B3","C":"C1"},
{"A":"A4","B":"B4","C":"C4"},
];
```

Below is the code which i tried

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('colFilter', ['ui', 'ui.filters']);
app.controller("colFilterCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.columnList = [{
        colid: 1,
        name:"A"
        }, {
        colid: 2,
        name: "B"
       }, {
        colid: 3,
        name: "C"
       }];

$scope.Value=[{"A":"A1","B":"B1","C":"C1"},
              {"A":"A2","B":"B2","C":"C2"},
              {"A":"A3","B":"B1","C":"C3"},
              {"A":"A1","B":"B3","C":"C1"},
              {"A":"A4","B":"B4","C":"C4"},
];
};
</script>
<div id="colFilterApp" data-ng-app="colFilter">
    <div id="colFilterAppCtrl" data-ng-controller="colFilterCtrl" >
<select  id="column" name="columns" ng-options="column.name for column in columnList" ng-model="selectedItem">
     <option value="All">--Select--</option>
</select>
<select  id="value" name="values">
     <option value="All">--Select--</option>
     <option ng-repeat="val in Value"  value="{{val.selectedItem}}">{{val.selectedItem}}</option>
</select> 
</div>
</div>
```

Any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code snippet.

1. put `$scope.$watch` on `selectedItem`
2. use `$scope.Value.filter`

```js
function colFilterCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.selectedItem = '';
  $scope.search = [];

  $scope.columnList = [{
    colid: 1,
    name: "A"
  }, {
    colid: 2,
    name: "B"
  }, {
    colid: 3,
    name: "C"
  }];

  $scope.Value = [
    {"A":"A1","B":"B1","C":"C1"},
    {"A":"A2","B":"B2","C":"C2"},
    {"A":"A3","B":"B1","C":"C3"},
    {"A":"A1","B":"B3","C":"C1"},
    {"A":"A4","B":"B4","C":"C4"}
  ];


  $scope.$watch('selectedItem', function() {
    $scope.search = [];
    $scope.Value.filter(function(obj) {
      let values = Object.values(obj)[Object.keys(obj).indexOf($scope.selectedItem.name)];
      $scope.search.push(values);
    });
    
    // remove duplicate values
    $scope.search = $scope.search.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return $scope.search.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="colFilterCtrl">
    
    <select name='columns' id="column"  ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="column as column.name for column in columnList"> <option value="" disabled>Select</option> </select>
            
    <select name='values' id="value" ng-model="selectSubCategory" ng-options="o as o for o in search" required> <option value="" disabled>Select</option> </select>
      
  </div> 
      
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.This was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It is called cascading dropdown. Here I have created a fiddle kindly check it and let me know https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/u50hgn5a/1741/

```
$scope.$watch('first', function () {
        $scope.Seconds = allSeconds.filter(function (s) {
            return s.firstId == $scope.first.Id;
        });
        $scope.city = {};
        $scope.Second = {};
        $scope.cities = [];
    });
```

Here I have created a `$watch` when first dropdown changes it will hit. instead to `$watch` you can bind data by using `ng-click` click event.

Comment: Thanks But i needed my json to be working in this style

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more example. In this example, a data object is being created that contains a mapping for each first drop-down items which can be populated via a database in near future. Here is the JSFiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/whb1saxg/1/

```
$scope.columnList = [
                    {
                        colid: 1,
                        name: "A"
                    }, {
                        colid: 2,
                        name: "B"
                    }, {
                        colid: 3,
                        name: "C"
                    }
                ];

                $scope.selectedItem = $scope.selectedItemValues  = [];

                $scope.childValues = {
                    "A": [{
                        colid: 1,
                        name: "A1"
                    }, {
                        colid: 2,
                        name: "A2"
                    }, {
                        colid: 3,
                        name: "A3"
                    }],

                    "B": [{
                        colid: 4,
                        name: "B1"
                    }, {
                        colid: 5,
                        name: "B2"
                    }, {
                        colid: 6,
                        name: "B3"
                    }],
                    "C": [{
                        colid: 7,
                        name: "C1"
                    }, {
                        colid: 8,
                        name: "C2"
                    }, {
                        colid: 9,
                        name: "C3"
                    }]
                };
$scope.ddlChange = function () {
                $scope.Value = ($scope.selectedItem !== undefined) ? $scope.childValues[$scope.selectedItem.name] : [];
            };
```

Comment: Yeah this may be useful  someday